# Error switching to client management

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

This is embarrassing. I've been a ColdFusion developer for 13 years and I've never had a reason to use client management over session management. Anyway, I've set up a database and datasource in CFAdmin, then selected that datasource as the default storage mechanism for client sessions.

Then I went through all my code and global-replaced all my session scopes with clients scope.

Top of my application.cfm looks like:

```
<CFAPPLICATION 
    NAME="blah"
    SESSIONMANAGEMENT="No"
    SESSIONTIMEOUT=#CreateTimeSpan(0,2,0,0)#
    CLIENTMANAGEMENT="Yes"
    CLIENTSTORAGE="sys_blah"
>
```

In my application.cfm, I had previously set a few variables globally related to session authentication, i.e.

```
<cfparam name="session.user.authenticated" default="0">
<cfparam name="session.user.id" default="">
```

However, now that these are written as

```
<cfparam name="client.user.authenticated" default="0">
<cfparam name="client.user.id" default="">
```

I get an error:

> Element USER is undefined in CLIENT.

What might I be doing wrong?

I can see the client vars going into the newly-created database.
I'm on CF12

Comment: `<cfdump var="#client#'>` gets you started.  Your embarrassment is justified for not knowing this after 13 years.

Comment: Respectfully, I disagree. They did not say they do not know how to use cfdump or that they had not tried it ;-) We all get tripped up by small stuff on occasion, despite years of experience. Sometimes you just need a little jolt or second set of eyes to nudge you back on track.  Especially for those that work solo. The problem may be that CF is treating the key name as `user.id`, rather than a structure named `user`, with a key named `id`. Of course, that brings us back around to Dan's first point, which I *do* agree with :) You should use `cfdump` to confirm or disprove that theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Client variables must be **simple data types**: strings, numbers, lists,
>   Booleans, or date and time values. They **cannot be** arrays, recordsets,
>   XML objects, query objects, or other **objects**. If you must store a
>   complex data type as a client variable, you can use the cfwddx tag to
>   convert the data to WDDX format (which is represented as a string),
>   store the WDDX data, and use the cfwddx tag to convert the data back
>   when you read it. For more information on using WDDX, see Using WDDX.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fd5.html

So... WDDX or JSON would work.

Comment: It should not be an issue in this case. IIRC, CF will treat "user.id" as the key name, ie string, rather than a structure. So both key name and value are simple objects.

Comment: really? then maybe he can try `client["user.authenticated"]`.  I have never used client storage.  The error message he posted does seem like CF is looking for a `user` object from the `client` scope.

Comment: Honestly, I have not used them in a long while, but that is my recollection. Had this thread not come up, I probably would not have remembered (or expected) it either after working with session variables for so long ;-)

Comment: What a pain to have to convert and deconvert to wddx every time I read and write these variables. I really don't want to rewrite all my code. I have tons of session vars in array format. Thanks for the answer anyway. I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @user460114 for array you can't get away, but for the user, if you don't count on it to be an object with methods, maybe you can store the dot notation as the key?  like `client["user.authenticated"]=blah`?

Comment: Though either way, you are probably going to have to change the code.